# The proper way to store/load statics in Ember App

Tags: ember.js

currently I'm thinking of the way to load statics into my Ember app.
The problem:

I have app branded logo, app name, app title (browser tab label), texts for routes etc.
What I'm doing now is the following:

```
 model() {
   let defaultHeaderModel = {
   logo: '/img/logo-cloud.svg',
   brand: {
     name: 'CloudCenter',
     logo: '/img/logo-cloud.svg'
   },
   userLinks: [{
     text: 'Logout',
     route: 'logout'
   }],
   navigation: [{
     text: 'Login',
     route: 'login'
   }]
 };
}
```

As you can see all of the values are hardcoded. What I'd like to do is to somehow load that "statics" and use them through some variables. For ex: `header.logo = resources.logo`.
My thoughts:

1) Use `environment` - store all of that values in the `config.js` and `import` it where needed. Cons: not sure if that data belongs to environment

2) ES6 POJO which can be imported to the app.

3) `.json` and some `staticsService` which will load `.json` file and through it I will have access to that values.

Are there any standardized approach to do such things? Or maybe better suggestions?

Comment: You could use a translation framework like `ember-i18n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create service, and have method(loadData) which will return Promise and will be resolved with your JSON data and update property in service. You need to call `loadData` in beforeModel hook, after the all the promises resolved only then it will move to model hook.

[Refer twiddle basic demonstration](https://ember-twiddle.com/9328d888dd094f98063b3a21d91fda0f?openFiles=services.my-service.js%2C)

services/my-service.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  defaultHeaderModel:{},
  loadData(){
    var myServiceDataLoadPromise = Ember.RSVP.Promise.resolve({one:1});
    myServiceDataLoadPromise.then(result =>{
      this.set('defaultHeaderModel',result);
    });
    return myServiceDataLoadPromise;
  }
});
```

routes/application.js
inside beforeModel hook, you can load service with data, it can be done any of the route which requires data.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  myService: Ember.inject.service(),
  beforeModel()
  {
    return Ember.RSVP.all([this.get('myService').loadData()]);
  }    
});
```

controllers/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  myService: Ember.inject.service(),
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle'
});
```

templates/application.hbs

```
{{myService.defaultHeaderModel.one}}
```

Comment: Yup, I know about route hooks and so on, what I need is the suggestion about in which way to store that values (separate `.json` file, environment or something other).

Comment: This is what I am following in my app, generally if its simple configuration data and it can be managed in client side then I prefer to go ahead with defining utils file which exports constants.(ie., Your second option). but definitely not `config.js` file(ie, first option). by the way there is no standard for this, at your convenience you can follow anything which suits your need and feels comfortable.